# How to remove punctuation marks from strings that have speacial meaning to "bash" in "C"

Tags: c, linux, string, bash, shell

I'm working on an email client in C language on my linux system, and bash helped me alot with implementing some small hacks.

The C client fetches an email and redirects the string or data to a script that have other things to do with that data or line of string.

But the problem is that sometime the "line of string" that is fetched from the online email account have special punctuation characters which when piped to the shell script, in most cases the script fails to execute while rarely changes the meaning of the original task of the script.

This is very similar to SQL Injection attacks.

I believe this could be very dangerous as well, imagine an email sent to you by someone which contains some shell commands which could wipe off your HDD or something similar.?

Right now the problem that is very common to me is that most of the "Subject" and "FROM" header fields of an email contains quoted strings which when piped to  that script it causes errors like:

```
sh: 1: cannot open myemail@gmail.com: No such file
sh: 3: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

These two header fields are supposed to be piped are first appended as in C:

```
 char *Subject=getSubject();
 char *From=getFrom();
 char completeString[256];
 sprintf(completeString,"./MyShellScript.sh \"Subject: %s and From: %s\"",Subject,From);
 /* Then executed via the system call */
 system(completeString);
```

I think the problem is that i have already provided quotes for the strings but when the "Subject" or "FROM" is already in quotes then the script gives the above shown errors.

Basically the shell script has a line for string input like this:

```
someOtherProgram -w=/tmp/temp.txt "$1"

This line expects a String like this "Hello Subject" and not ""Hello Subject""
```

What to i do.?

Comment: Bluntly, don't do anything even remotely like this. Replace the shell script with C code and scan the string for any characters not 100% known to be safe.

Comment: Bash is written in C. What makes you think bash can do something you cannot do in C?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, "scan the string for any characters not 100% known to be safe" -- I disagree, strongly, with that approach: You can't always reasonably restrict your input domain to such a small whitelist as to make it safe to pass data in a context where it's able to be parsed as code, and attempts to do so make the systems making that attempt less flexible (since they're restricting their input domains unnecessarily). Far, far better to simply *pass data out-of-band from code*, such that it can't ever be parsed in the first place. This is why the answer to SQL injection is bind variables.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, ...now, there are places where in-band signaling is baked into protocol design (hello, HTML), and *there* you need to sanitize your data. But that's a design failure to get into that situation in the first place.

Comment: (As an aside -- it's best to avoid using extensions, including `.sh`, for executables; using them means you need to change all your other programs when you rewrite something in a different language, and also they imply that something can be started with `sh`, encouraging the actual shebang used to start a script to be bypassed/ignored).

Comment: (I have a big rant about databases with wire protocols using in-band data transmission and thus try to quote and escape bind-variable content -- it's better than what we have here, because at least in database-land the client library is presumably produced by the same vendor who makes the database, so the chances of making mistakes is less than if it were completely independent parties; but still, it's completely and utterly unnecessary risk that better design would avoid).

Comment: ...getting back towards shell-land: You don't know which implementation of `sh` your user has, what extensions it implements, what vulnerabilities it has, etc -- so any attempt at implementing your own escaping is doomed to failure when J. Random Shell treats `=(...)` as a command substitution variant. The way to win that battle is not to play: If data is never parsed as code, and appropriate precautions are taken elsewhere (ie. [*never* using `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)), then there aren't opportunities for new/unexpected syntax or parser bugs to trip one up.

Comment: stripping characters from strings can have bad results.  ***people have died*** because of corrupted SMS messages.  instead you should use one of the other methods mentioned here. (exec or setenv) it's also possible to quote and escape strings to make them safe but only if you can be sure about what system() is going to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't **ever** call `system(completeString)` with a string generated from untrusted data. Instead, pass the arguments out-of-band from the invocation by using an `execv`-family call:

```
pid_t pid = fork()
int status;
if (pid < 0) {                                                       /* the fork failed */
  exit(1);
} else if (pid > 0) {                       /* the fork succeeded, and we're the parent */
  /* wait for the child to exit and collect its status */
  waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
} else {                                     /* the fork succeeded, and we're the child */
  /*            replace ourselves (as the child process) with an instance of the script */
  /*     executable         argv[0]          argv[1]  argv[2] terminator                */
  execlp("./MyShellScript", "MyShellScript", Subject, From,   NULL);
}
```

---

On the other hand, if you really want to use `system()`, you can use a constant string and pass your variables via the environment:

```
/* this is a hardcoded string; it includes "$Subject", **not** the actual subject
 * given to you by the remote system.
 */
const char shellScript[] = "./MyShellScript \"$Subject\" \"$From\"";

/* ...then, after we have a subject, we can set them in the environment */
if(setenv("Subject", Subject, 1) == 0 && setenv("From", From, 1) == 0) {
  system(shellScript);
  unsetenv("Subject"); /* avoid leaking data to other parts or children of your program */
  unsetenv("From");
} else {            /* setenv failed -- maybe we were run with a very full environment? */
                     /* (or maybe the remote user provided a too-large Subject or From) */
  exit(1); 
}
```

This is safe because *the expansion is performed only after the shell has been started*: The code that's actually invoked by the copy of `sh -c` started by `system()` is the constant string that you've (hopefully) audited to be correct.

Note that since environment variables are automatically converted to shell variables, you don't strictly even need to pass `"$Subject"` and `"$From"` in your explicit command -- if you made the environment part of `MyShellScript`'s documented calling convention, it could simply refer directly to `"$Subject"` and `"$From"` and see the values that were placed in the environment via `setenv()`.

Comment: Thank you that's what i needed, sorry for being late to respond but i actually went to sleep after having that situation, so before responding i wanted to implement and see how it works, but it worked for me, so i accepted as an Answer. :)